# WPF datagrid with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a datagrid in WPF to my ViewModel so that it will update any cell changes to the database as well as allow the user to delete rows and add new rows.  I've got part of it working but can't find a ELEGANT solution for the ADD and modify.
here is the xaml

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,41,0,0" Name="dataGrid1"   
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAllItems}" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ItemListID}" Header="ID" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Header="Name" Width="4*" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}" Header="Active" Width="*"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

then in my view model method

```
private ObservableCollection< ItemsList> getAllItems()
{
    using (var context = new InspectorGeneralEntities())
    {
        var query = from I in context.ItemsLists
                    select I;

        var item = new ObservableCollection<ItemsList>(query.ToList());
        return item;
    }
}
```

Deleting a row or modifying a row on the datagrid does not flow onto the database.

a) what other binding do i need to create in the xaml code that will detect these events

b) How do i detect a removed record or modified item in the view model so that I can update the datacontext if it won't automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of your ObservableCollection. The event handler  receives an instance of the [NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx) class which contains a property 'Action' describing if rows have been added or removed. It also contains lists of the rows that have been added ('NewItems') or removed ('OldItems'). That should give you enough information to update your database.

You could implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your row ViewModel (class `ItemsList` I guess) and then subscribe to it, to find out if a row is dirty and needs to be updated in the database. The interface consists of a single event `PropertyChanged` that is to be raised in the property setters of your ViewModel whenever a value changes.

You're right the NotifyCollectionChanged event comes too early for an immediate insert to the database. But you can flag the row as 'inserted' in the event handler and insert it as soon as the last property changed event (see above) required to complete the row occurs.

Comment: Two issues;
 
1)NotifyCollectionChangedAction will only fire if you add a New Row or Delete and existing row NOT if you modify a cell in an existing row.  ie no way to tell if row is dirty.
 
2) When you first start to type in the NEW row the NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add is fired before you have had a chance to fill in all the cells. You can't add an empty row to the db especially if there are still null fields at this point.  So again you must use the Update..which again i can't figure out how to capture.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems with the code in your question. But the reason why deleting a row is not reflected in the database is the *.ToList()* -- essentially you're creating a new list which is a copy of *query* and the grid is removing elements from that copy.

You should use a **ListCollectionView** and use a **Filter** instead of a linq statement.

Here's a sample showing how to do it:

1) Create a new WPF project called *ListCollectionViewTest*

2) In the MainWindow.xaml.cs cut&paste the following (should be in ViewModel but I'm too lazy)

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    namespace ListCollectionViewTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private List<Employee> equivalentOfDatabase = new List<Employee>()
                        {
                            new Employee() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", IsWorthyOfAttention = true },
                            new Employee() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", IsWorthyOfAttention = true },
                            new Employee() { FirstName = "Mr.", LastName = "Unsignificant", IsWorthyOfAttention = false },
                        };

            public ListCollectionView TestList { get; set; }
            public MainWindow()
            {
                DataContext = this;

                // This is all the magic you need -------
                TestList = new ListCollectionView(equivalentOfDatabase);
                TestList.Filter = x => (x as Employee).IsWorthyOfAttention;

                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(equivalentOfDatabase.Aggregate("Employees are: \n\r", (acc, emp) => acc + string.Format("    - {0} {1}\n\r", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName), x => x));
            }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public bool IsWorthyOfAttention { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

3) In MainWindow.xaml cut&paste this:

```
    <Window x:Class="ListCollectionViewTest.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"
                      RowHeight="22"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Content="Show All Employees in DB" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>        
    </Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data context doesn't exist at the time you would be making udpates.  You are using a 'using' statement which destroys the context.  The only reason you are seeing data is that you have forced a query to run against your DB (via the .ToList() statement).  To answer your questions:

a) nothing more is needed specifically for binding
b) Calling SaveChanges() on your InspectorGeneralEntities() context will update any changes in your db.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new ViewModel CLass:ItemGridVM to represent each row object ie ItemGridVM exposes the Item class properties you are binding in your datagrid.
eg:

```
public class ItemGridVM : BaseViewModel
    {
    private Item _item;//an instance of Item class
      public int ItemId
              {
                  get
                  {
                      return _item.ItemId;
                  }
                  set
                  {
                      _item.ItemId = value;
                      //if you want UI changes : raise PropertyChanged Notification and binding in UI should be Update SourceTrigger:PropertyChanged
                  }
        }
   //Contains Commands :UpdateItem,EditItem,DeleteItem
}
```

Now in yourMainViewModel you can create an Observable COllection of ItemGridVM as:

```
private ObservableCollection<ItemGridVM> _getAllItems;

public ObservableCollection<ItemGridVM> GetAllItems
{
get
            {
                return _getAllItems;
            }
            set
            {
                _getAllItems = value;
                //if u want Observable Collection to get updated on edit either 
                RaisePropertyChanged("GetAllItems");

            }
}
```

Now in case of any action on any row the command binds to ItemGridVM.So u get the row details as exposed properties.
I resolved the same issue using this.(Pure MVVM)