# Raise an event in datagridview to update database for delete or update MVVM method

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagridview

I think I am missing something simple but I am basically doing a multiple step method to get my data.  Let me run through a simpler version of what I am doing in an example.

1. I have an observable collection that implements INotifyPropertyChanged
2. The Observable Collection is of a class 'POCO' which is a simple POCO class that makes up these two properties:

   ```
   PersonID int { get; set; }
   Name string { get; set; }
   ```
3. I have an entity to sql data model that maps a simple database table that contains the same  meta values in the POCO class and let's say for simple example it has three row values:

   ```
   PersonID, Name
   1,  Brett
   2,  Emily
   3,  Test
   ```
4. The observable collection is wired in ModelView like so:

   ```
   ObservableCollection<POCO> _Pocos;
   POCOEntities ee = new POCOEntities();

   public ObservableCollection<POCO> POCOs
   {
       get
       {
           if (_Pocos == null)
           {
               List<POCO> mes = this.GetPOCOs();
               _Pocos= new ObservableCollection<POCO>(mes);
           }

           return _Pocos;
       }
       set
       {
           _Pocos = value;

           OnPropertyChanged("POCOs");
       }
   }

   List<POCO> GetPOCOs()
   {
       return ee.vPOCO.Select(p => new POCOView()
           {
               PersonId = p.PersonID,
               Name = p.Name
           }).ToList();
   }
   ```
5. I also have a Current Item wired up as such.

   ```
   POCO _CurrentPOCO;

   public POCO CurrentPOCO
   {
       get { return _CurrentPOCO; }
       set
       {
           _CurrentPOCO = value;

           OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPOCO");
       }
   }
   ```
6. 4 and 5 are the guts of the ModelView I wire them up to the view of the datagrid as such:

   ```
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding POCOs}" 
         CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentPOCO}" />
   ```
7. This is the part that I do not get, how do I update the database's entity model in near real time?  The collection is wired up just fine and updating, how do I tell the database what happened?  If I set up an event like 'CellEditEnding' or 'SelectionChanged' and try to implement an update proc from my entity model it BOMBS in the ModelView.  If I stick to just the code behind it works, kind of, but does not seem to capture the 'after' changed value.

Even with using the ICommand property and implementing the relay command done in the MVVM.  These methods won't work.  So I was curious if I am over thinking it and their some type of interface you can just bake in that will do the refreshing to the database for you.  I can handle inserting docs and then using a method to populate or refresh the datagrid but I would like to be able to change values in the datagridview and update the database directly.

**SUMMARY: 
In the simplest way possible I am just wanting to update the database as I change the datagridview and the observablecollection changes so the two sync with each other.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two categories of changes here:

1. The collection changes, i.e. items are added and/or removed. To track these changes, make your VM listen to the `ObservableCollection`'s `CollectionChanged` event and use the `NewItems` and `OldItems` properties to figure out what data to add and/or remove from the DB.
2. Properties on one of your POCO instances changes, e.g. you change the name of a person. A change like this will not trigger a `CollectionChanged` event as the collection itself is still the same.

For #2 I would implement a simple Viewmodel for the POCO class that handles updates to its properties. After all, your POCO should be considered a business object and should not be exposed to the view directly. Each PocoVM holds a reference to a single POCO instance.

## EDIT

I added more or less all of the code I used in my experiement, except for the stubbed database since I have no idea what you are using and how it works. It doesn't really matter as long as it returns lists of items and you can tell it to update a single item.

***XAML***
Same as yours except I added another grid (readonly) to show changes once they got accepted by my *MysticalDBLayer*. I also got rid of the `CurrentItem`as we will be using the `PocoVM` to keep track of which item we are editing.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock>Input-Grid</TextBlock>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding POCOs}"/>
    
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Readonly-Grid</TextBlock>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="3"
              ItemsSource="{Binding POCOs, Mode=OneWay}"
              IsReadOnly="True"/>
</Grid>
```

***View Model (DataContext of the XAML)***
This is all that goes into this file. The database connection might vary based on what you use, but basically I have an observable collection that I populate the same way you do, except I create a new PocoVM (viewmodel) for every POCO *and add the new PocoVM to the `ObservableCollection` instead of the POCO itself*.

```
class VM
{
    ObservableCollection<PocoVM> _pocoCollection = new ObservableCollection<PocoVM>();

    public ObservableCollection<PocoVM> POCOs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pocoCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                _pocoCollection = new ObservableCollection<PocoVM>();
                IEnumerable<POCO> pocos = MysticalDBLayer.GetItems();
                foreach (POCO poco in pocos)
                {
                    _pocoCollection.Add(new PocoVM(poco));
                }
            }
            return _pocoCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

***And finally the PocoVM***
Every time you try to update the value of one of your cells (only name will be update:able with this code as `Number` only has a getter), the corresponding setter will get called in this class. Here you can do your write to your DB and act based on whether that worked out or not.

```
class PocoVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private POCO _dataInstance = null;

    public PocoVM(POCO dataInstance)
    {
        _dataInstance = dataInstance;
    }

    public uint Number
    {
        get { return _dataInstance.Number; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _dataInstance.Name; }
        set
        {
            if (string.Compare(value, _dataInstance.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                return;

            if (!MysticalDBLayer.UpdatePoco(_dataInstance, new POCO(_dataInstance.Number, value)))
                return;

            _dataInstance.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Comment: Items are being updated, not added or removed.  I think this is the issue I keep running into with 'CollectionChanged' I am reading.  That and people mention it without a working example of it so I can hook it up and have it do nothing.  I did not think about the update at once and that may be an option.  This is not for a production class app.  Just a small app I am using for testing functionality.  I can actually do almost all of the answer except bind an ICOMMAND to a datagrid.  That seems to be not possible out of the box.  And I wish to follow MVVM so it would be beneficial to learn this.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow you. Are the "update database on changes" and "bind ICommand to datagrid" separate issues, or do you want to update via an ICommand "at all costs"?

Also, what part of the grid should trigger this update command?

Comment: Basically I have gotten to the point on my own I can fire 'CellEditEnding' and get ALMOST everything I need.  I needed to update the properties of my bindings to use 'UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged'.  Now my bindings are current to the moment, but I don't want to update till a 'change' to a cell happens.  My question was for any person's method but the answer I am coming up with through my own coding is to use 'CellEditEnding'.  However...  You cannot easily bind this to a 'Command' property like you can with other MVVM commands.  That is the rub, I don't want code behind.

Comment: For clarification I want simplest way to update change from A to B.  A change to collection is made, database is aware of it.  I don't have to use 'CellEditEnding' event and I would actually prefer to do it with an interface that is aware of changes and fires behind the scenes.  Problem I am finding in my own coding is that when property changes, it changes for every character, not when a whole cell is completed.  I would assume a proper event would know when 'POCO' object is done editing, then fire event, not before.

Comment: My code only updates once you press enter, or tab, or take focus away from the edited cell. All in pure MVVM goodness, no events, no code behind.

Comment: I did not see your updates since yesterday, that is more of what I was expecting.   I will check it later. My largest concern was I kept having updates as I was typing before when implementing INotifyProperty changed when I implemented 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged', however if I did not implement this it appeared to not take changes immediately.  Of course this was with using the event 'CellEditEnding', if the method of just doing the logic in the set of the property works, that is more of what I was hoping for in the first place.

Comment: Okay Zoltan I think you got my points as this is near exactly what I wanted.  Thanks so much, I knew it was something simple I was missing.  Just did not dawn on me to do more methods in my set operation.  What you said on the POCO View also made me think I should isolate the ViewModel of the POCO seperated from the VIewModel for the view as well.  Your first point also makes me want to learn more on how to set up the collection to act as cache and then write the changes to the database.  For now I just want to update directly as db is small and only a few thousand rows total SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only need to use the **CollectionChanged** event of the **ObservableCollection**.

Event arguments contains the **Action** (Add/Remove...) and you can get the **NewItems** and **OldItems** too.

So you can track the changes on the collection and do the synchronization with your database.
I hope I could help you.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you show a simple implementation?  Do you hook this up to a base class you implement or write add on methods in your viewmodel?  I know when you implement INotifyPropertyChanged you need to handle the PropertyChangedEventHandler.  How do you set the Collection Changed to understand on the entity model?

Comment: I would use it in the VM where you define the Collection. But you can use it for tracking Add and Remove, not for tracking Update.
                ObservableCollection<MyObject> objects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
                objects.CollectionChanged += objects_CollectionChanged;
                       void objects_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {}

Comment: What kind of update do you want to support? You can track Replace with this. If you overwrite the old item with the new, updated version of it.

Comment: Okay I will give it a shot, basically there will be descriptions that will change that are strings in the POCO model.  They will change a lot but doing a delete and new insert is not desired, simply an update to the db based on a proc that could be wired to an event would be preferable.

Comment: Okay this is only part of the answer, it hooks up events but does not explain how you bind them to an entity data model.  How do you hook up an entity model to bind the entity to this with an MVVM approach?  This could add functionality to an existing binding of observable collection but without knowing how to use that functionality it still does not address my question.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `ObservableCollection` which overrides `InsertItem()` and `RemoveItem()` methods:

```
public class CustomerCollection : ObservableCollection<Customer>
{
    private DataContext _db;

    public DataContext Db
    {
      get { return _db; }
    }

    public CustomerCollection(IEnumerable<Customer> customers, DataContext context)
      : base(customers)
    {
      _db = context;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Customer item)
    {
      this.Db.AddToCustomers(item);
      this.Db.SaveChanges();
      base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
      this.Db.DeleteObject(this[index]);
      this.Db.SaveChanges();
      base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could that be extended to overriding updates?  I don't care about inserts or deletes as much as updates.

Comment: @djangojazz How do you initialize your `ObservableCollection`? If you do like that: `myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(myEntities.Customers)` just use `myEntities.SaveChanges()` to commit the changes

Comment: It is in part 4 above.  I get a private property that gets a method that performs the population of the public collection property.  I have not tried your code though yet so I will try it as is for an class to use as a container, I was just curious if it will perform updates as is.  I can see them doing the inserts but not envisioning the updates.  The code xaml I am showing in part 6 above has a current item I could expose to perform an update one at a time.  The issue with this method being that I would have to do this one item selection at a time, which is tedious.

Comment: This does not have methods to 'AddtoCustomers' or 'DeleteObject' when you extend the DataContext.  If I am using the right namespace and using the DataContext as part of System.Data.Linq I only get methods shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx.  Where you using a different DataContext Namespace possibly or an earlier version?  I was trying 4.0.

Answer (score -1):

This is similar to a question I just answered here [WPF datagrid with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007389/wpf-datagrid-with-mvvm). (Because I'm a newbie to this site, I will copy the answer)

You should use a **ListCollectionView**.

Here's a sample showing how to do it:

1) Create a new WPF project called *ListCollectionViewTest*

2) In the MainWindow.xaml.cs cut&paste the following (should be in ViewModel but I'm too lazy)

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    namespace ListCollectionViewTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private List<Employee> equivalentOfDatabase = new List<Employee>()
                        {
                            new Employee() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", IsWorthyOfAttention = true },
                            new Employee() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", IsWorthyOfAttention = true },
                            new Employee() { FirstName = "Mr.", LastName = "Unsignificant", IsWorthyOfAttention = false },
                        };

            public ListCollectionView TestList { get; set; }
            public MainWindow()
            {
                DataContext = this;

                // This is all the magic you need -------
                TestList = new ListCollectionView(equivalentOfDatabase);
                TestList.Filter = x => (x as Employee).IsWorthyOfAttention;

                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(equivalentOfDatabase.Aggregate("Employees are: \n\r", (acc, emp) => acc + string.Format("    - {0} {1}\n\r", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName), x => x));
            }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public bool IsWorthyOfAttention { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

3) In MainWindow.xaml cut&paste this:

```
    <Window x:Class="ListCollectionViewTest.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"
                      RowHeight="22"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Content="Show All Employees in DB" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>        
    </Window>
```

Comment: I can already get everything I want with an observable collection but the part you are not showing.  How do you wire it to talk to the database?  You need an event when your collection changes to notify via which member changed.  All you are doing is mapping a collection to a datagridview and then clicking a button to show members.  Plus your method is not showing when the members are removed as if I remove them from you datagrid and click the button the collection is not aware when they are removed.  That is thepoint I thought of using ObservableCollection as it 'observes' when things change.

Comment: To wire it with the database, I would derive ListCollectionView and override the *OnCollectionChanged* method to handle the create and delete operations and I would make Employee implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* to handle the update operations. Granted, the *ObservableCollection* way is also viable with the *CollectionChanged* event.

Comment: I already implemented INotifyPropertyChanged if you read my question.  I think the things you are saying to do is what no one is showing accurately how to do. That is why I set a bounty.  The answers I am getting is the equivalent if someone asked me how to query for data to just say: "Use Linq with Entity Framework".  It is valid, but not descriptive.  How do you use 'OnCollectionChanged' to fire at correct times with overrides?  To just hook up more functionality without a working example of how to use it is where I am not following.